# Javascript (Ionic Framework)- Webscrape behind a Login page

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, authentication, web-scraping, autologin

I am having trouble find out how to use Javascript to login to a website to access some information "https://wrem.sis.yorku.ca/Apps/WebObjects/ydml.woa/wa/DirectAction/document?name=CourseListv1" the page redirects to the login page at https://passportyork.yorku.ca/ppylogin/ppylogin which can only be accessed by being redirected ( I cannot seem to get it working. The login uses POST to authenticate. I cant seem to find any answers on how to do this with Javascript, only other languages. If anyone knows how I can just get the login working that would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Check out Phanthomjs

Comment: I'm using the ionic framework https://ionicframework.com/ to develop the app I'm trying to make I don't think I could use that in my case since I wont have a server to run it on, instead I'm trying to just get the javascript to scrape the data, manipulate a bit and then display it to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I need more information to guide you in the correct direction. But if your using NodeJS you can use a library like [superagent](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/) (Check out the **Preserving cookies** section to keep the session open after the login is done). All you have to do is analyze the flow of the web you are scrapping (Chrome DevTools is great for that) and make the same requests.

[Phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org) was mentioned, even though is a great tool, it's also really slow for scrapping, only use this if you need the javascript in the target site to be evaluated.